# Can viruses pass through sweat pores?

Tags: pathology, virus, skin, immune-system

I have read somewhere that viruses and other microbes can not penetrate skin but what about sweat pores? Can viruses pass through these pores?

Comment: How would you expect that it would be determined that viruses cannot penetrate skin? Some theoretical method, performed by pipe-smoking tweed-suited academics at a blackboard, or by testing whether viruses can infect via skin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Pore' is a confusing term. Sweat is produced in sweat *glands*, and subsequently excreted through a *duct*, as indicated in the image below (sudoriferous ~).

In short, viruses cannot enter the body through these glands because the glands don't really open up into the body, but instead the inside of the sweat gland is lined with sweat-producing cells (fig 2 and 3).

A passive protection mechanism preventing infection is similar to the mechanism by which the bladder is guarded from infection through the urethra: even if some malignant agent were to enter the sweat duct, it is simply pushed out by the excreted sweat.

[image: Sweat glands in skin]

**Figure one**: Sweat glands in skin. Source: wikimedia commons.

[image: Sweat gland slide]
<sub>(source: [uwa.edu.au](http://www.lab.anhb.uwa.edu.au/mb140/corepages/integumentary/Images/swa020he.jpg))</sub>

**Figure two**: Slide of sweat gland. Tightly packed secretory cells dump sweat into the lumen through exocytosis (see fig 3). Source: University of Western Australia.

[image: Merocrine exocytosis]

**Figure three**: Exocytosis. The lining of the sweat gland contains cells producing sweat through exocytosis. Viruses and other pathogens cannot simply enter these cells, and also cannot 'slip in between' the cells. Source: wikimedia commons.

Comment: It would be great, if you can at least add the sources for the images. Additionally references for further reading would also be good.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had the sources in figure alt-text, but this is much better. Will look at further reading later